# How do you cycle through and display parameters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose you have a URL like `http://www.somesite.com/somepage.html?id=1&page=2&field=3`

Now with jQuery I would like to display all of the GET variables passed to the page. How do I dodo this. Its fine (perhaps even better) if its done as part of some Debug function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look at the window.location.href variable.

Here is a nice guide performing exactly what you want: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Basically extend jQuery with getUrlVars:

```
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
});
```

Then use it:

```
var allVars = $.getUrlVars();
var byName = $.getUrlVar('name');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(){

var $_GET = {};

jQuery.each( document.location.search.substr(1).split( "&" ), function(index, value ){
var split = value.split("=");
$_GET[decodeURIComponent( split[0] )] = decodeURIComponent( split[1] );
});

window.$_GET = $_GET;

})();
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5079/discussion-between-minitech-and-esailija)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.search`. Here's a quick function that will return the parameters as an object:

```
function getParameters() {
    var parameters = {};
    var splitStr = window.location.search.substring(1).split(/[&=]/);
    var i, key, value;

    for(i = 0; typeof (key = splitStr[i], value = splitStr[i + 1]) !== 'undefined'); i += 2) {
        parameters[decodeURIComponent(key)] = decodeURIComponent(value);
    }

    return parameters;
}
```